# How to handle URL redirects in SwiftUI?

Tags: url, redirect, download, swiftui, favicon

I have the following code that fills an Image with the favicon of a website:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var website = "https://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico"
    @State var favicon : String?
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            
            if favicon != nil {
            Image(uiImage: favicon!.toImage()!)
            }
            
            TextField("Sito", text: $website).padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                website = "https://www." + website + ".com/favicon.ico"
            }, label: {
                Text("Complete URL")
            }).padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                if let url = URL(string: website) {
                let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [self] (data,response,error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    if let data = data {
                        var immagineTemp : UIImage = UIImage(systemName: "questionmark")!
                        if UIImage(data: data) != nil {
                        immagineTemp = UIImage(data: data)!
                        } else {
                            debugPrint("URL was redirected")
                        }
                        favicon = immagineTemp.toString()
                    }
                }
                session.resume()
            }
            }, label: {
                Text("Get favicon")
            }).padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

extension String {
    func toImage() -> UIImage? {
        if let data = Data(base64Encoded: self, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters){
            return UIImage(data: data)
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func toString() -> String? {
        let data: Data? = self.pngData()
        return data?.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithLineFeed)
    }
}
```

Usually, the var website is empty and can be filled throught the TextField, but for the purpose of this example I filled it with that URL, because if you use the Stackoverflow website to download the favicon, as I wrote in the code above, it doesn't work because the URL "https://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico" redirects you to "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196", which is where the Stackoverflow favicon is. Because of this, "immagineTemp = UIImage(data: data)!" results nil, and it goes in the brackets where there's the debugPrint("URL was redirected").

What I would like it to do, is to automatically detect the fact that a URL redirects you to another one, so that it can continue on its own to download the favicon. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: As far as I tried the URL `https://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico` returns a 301 response with `https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico,https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196` (not `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196`) and the redirected URL return the 404 response. It seems to be the server side issue.

Comment: Up until this morning, when I tried to visit `https://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico` I kept getting redirected to the other website I linked.. But what about redirected URLs in general? Is there a way to automatically handle them?

Comment: "Is there a way to automatically handle them?"> With using default configuration like in your code, redirects are automatically handled in URLSession. And I tried again just now, the original URL returned 301 response with `location: https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico,https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196`. You may be missing the first part or it has abruptly changed since after this morning.

Comment: What do you mean by "the first part"?

Comment: The `location:` contains `https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico` as the first part and `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196` as the second part separated by comma.

Comment: Ok, but what I mean is, I would know that it has two parts until I run the code, so user wouldn't be able to add the missing part in order to download the favicon..

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. Anyway, URLSession can handle redirect response if server returns proper redirect response.

Comment: I mean that with the code I wrote above, the favicon for the Stackoverflow website isn't downloaded because there's that part you wrote that is missing. How can the code above work with websites that behave like Stackoverflow does?

Comment: Tell the engineer of stackoverflow to return the right response.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought you could cast the response (which is of type `URLResponse`) as an `HTTPURLResponse`, then check the property `statusCode` of that object.

But on further inspection, it seems like the way to go is to implement `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`, and more specifically the following method:

```swift
optional func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
                               task: URLSessionTask, 
willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, 
                 newRequest request: URLRequest, 
                  completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void)
```

See the Apple documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411626-urlsession